# jQuery - How to convert a jQuery object to the kind of object returned w/ getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Occasionally I come across situations where certain I have to use `document.getElementById()` in order to get certain code to work (like w/ Google Maps API for example) for reasons I don't understand. Is there a jQuery method or some relatively easy way to convert a jQuery object to the sort of object returned w/ `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: FYI: That "sort of element" is usually called a DOM element, as opposed to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$("#myId").get(0)
```

or

```
$("#myId")[0]
```

Comment: NOTE: Within jQuery functions like .each() and .click(), `this` is `=` to `$(this).get(0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can do `$("#someDiv").get(0)` which will return the `HTMLElement` object (which is the same that is returned by calling `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @kanaka - Correct. However, using `get(#)` allows you to do things such as negative index to get elements from the end of an array. Using bracket notation would not allow this.

Comment: true, but the question is about document.getElementById which always returns a single element.

Comment: @kanaka And it's less processing for jQuery to use `[0]` :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get the underlying DOM node using

```
$(myselector)[0]
```

or

```
$(myselector).get(0)
```

In addition to the above:

`$(myselector).get()`, without an index, will return an array of DOM nodes.